# Query date range in Mongoid 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

How do you query a date range using Mongoid 5.1? I'm trying something like

```
Data.find(sid: 7, :created_at => (Time.parse('5-07-2015')..Time.now ))
```

but that gives me an error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just use:

`Data.where(:created_at => (Time.parse('5-07-2015')..Time.now))`

or in your case since it ranges from 5-07-2015 to now then you can just do

`Data.where(:created_at.gte => Time.parse('5-07-2015'))`

Answer (score 1):

`.find` method is supposed to be used for looking up a record with a particular id.

You must be using `find_by`

```
Data.find_by(sid: 7, created_at: (Time.parse('5-07-2015')..Time.now ))
```